# Regex not matching certain fragments of a string

Tags: c#, regex

This is **not** a question on manipulating HTML. It wasn't clear in my previous post so I'm following the advice and repost it.

I have a long string that, for visualization's sake, can be displayed as an XML. I'm trying to manipulate chunks of the code. Also, the question contains a list of steps on how I figured when constructing the pattern. The question is (also) about where I went wrong.

I'm trying to match tags with certain names and "ignore" them using the following code.

```
foreach (string ignoree in ignorees)
{
  Regex regex = new Regex("<" + ignoree + "[^>]*>.+</" + ignoree + ">");
  text = regex.Replace(text, "&");
}
```

This works as excepted for simple tags but fails for complex ones, i.e. such tag that have children in them. At least I **think** that's the signature of the issue, as far I've seen.

I'm guessing that it's got to do with the closing jaws of one of the child-tags but I can't for the life of me see the problem.

The regex goes like this:

1. pick a start-jaws followed by the tag name
2. match it greedily with some or no characters not being end-jaws
3. when end-jaws are found, match greedily at least a single character
4. when end-jaws followed by start-jaws are found, match the tag name
5. match with end-jaws

The problem is that I can match the **cc** tag but not the **dd** one.

```xml
<aa>
  <bb>
    <cc>c</cc>
    <dd>
      <ee>e</ee>
    </dd>
  </bb>
  <bb>
    <cc>c</cc>
    <dd>
      <ee>e</ee>
    </dd>
  </bb>
</aa>
```

```xml
<aa>
  <bb>
    &
    <dd>
      <ee>e</ee>
    </dd>
  </bb>
  <bb>
    &
    <dd>
      <ee>e</ee>
    </dd>
  </bb>
</aa>
```

Comment: Either explain why it is *not XML* or use normal XML parser to read it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Because XML starts with a schema tag, requires a root tag and consists of coherent tags (open/close). None of these conditions is fulfilled here. Also, it's possible that the jaws ("<" and ">") will be exchanged for something else, an other delimiter. Now, can **someone** please give me a hint instead of closing the question with referral to another one that doesn't really relates? SO very grumpy today...

Comment: @KonradViltersten your sample in question is a valid xml. Can you post another sample showing how it is not an xml...

Comment: @KonradViltersten Side note on XML: "XML starts with a schema tag" - I have no idea what that means; "requires a root tag" - to extent, you can read XML without root in "document fragments" mode; "open/close pairs" - indeed, but there are no samples of mismatches in you posts.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You asked why it's "sort of" an XML. That's the answer. The question relates to the "sort of" tag not being matched. There's no HTML/XML manipulation required. It seems I didn't managed to get through the pre-assumptions, altough I was trying to do my best to clarify that it's a regex-question. Not sure how to improve it so I asked on Meta. Maybe someone there have something helpful. And I'm still curious on my bullet list as to where I figure wrongly...

Comment: @L.B It **happens** to be sort-of valid XML. There are no guarantees it stays so. I could give this example: <aa><bb>&<dd><ee>e</ee></dd></bb><bb>&<dd><ee>e</ee></dd></bb></aa></aa>

Comment: @KonradViltersten Still can be parsed by HtmlAgilityPack. Now post what you want to the with this *"invalid xml"*, so we can show  how it can be done without regex :)

Comment: @L.B Well, I need to replace e.g. a string starting with "!name§" followed by a bunch of text and ending with "!Zname½" by a text "ignore". The string is a part of a much longer string. It **seemed** to me (note the past tense) that it was a good idea to express the issue as a XML'ishly looking question...

Comment: Doesn't really matter if this is actually valid XML or not: handling nested paired delimiters is one of the things that is simply a pain in the rear to do with regexes. That's why you're getting advice to use a different tool from multiple people.

Comment: @KonradViltersten then, would you update your question with better samples and expected outputs (and edited regex in question; since your regex doesn't seem to match that strings).....

Comment: @L.B At the moment, the samples show what I'm getting because I mapped some characters to tag-look-alikes for better readability. I suspect that we're setting ourselves off on a wild goose chase here. I tried to come up with the minimal example presenting the issue and I'm afraid that I'm not able to produce more relevant information still retaining the clarity of the question.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I am convinced that this is an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=xy+problem)

Comment: @L.B Possibly, mate. My other aim is, though, to refresh my regex chi, so I wanted to hit two birds with one stone. One of the repliers claims that he got it to work so I'm pretty sure it's possible. But it's fully possible that I **think** I need X, while I really need **Y**. I also could be that every problem is a nail if you only got a hammer. And since people generally don't know regex, they might tend to suggest a different approach. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you use lazy matching?

```
Regex regex = new Regex("<" + ignoree + "[^>]*>.*?</" + ignoree + ">");
```

Furthermore, do you use multiline matching?

If one runs the following code:

```
string text = "<aa><bb><cc>c</cc><dd><ee>e</ee></dd></bb><bb><cc>c</cc><dd><ee>e</ee></dd></bb>‌​</aa> and <aa><bb>&<dd><ee>e</ee></dd></bb><bb>&<dd><ee>e</ee></dd></bb></aa>";
foreach(string ignoree in new string[] {"dd","cc"}) {
    Regex regex = new Regex("<" + ignoree + "[^>]*?>.*?</" + ignoree + ">");
    text = regex.Replace(text, "&");
}
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

The result is (formatted, indentation not part of the result):

```
<aa>
    <bb>&&</bb>
    <bb>&&</bb>‌
​</aa>
and
<aa>
    <bb>&&</bb>
    <bb>&&</bb>
</aa>
```

Comment: There's only one, single line. No breaks. Also, can you explain the lazy match in the middle? I thought we should have greedy on both quantifiers...

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you referring to the string I'm parsing? It's in my question (with added line breaks for your convenience). Are you looking for this: <aa><bb><cc>c</cc><dd><ee>e</ee></dd></bb><bb><cc>c</cc><dd><ee>e</ee></dd></bb></aa>
 and 
<aa><bb>&<dd><ee>e</ee></dd></bb><bb>&<dd><ee>e</ee></dd></bb></aa>

Comment: @KonradViltersten: I am however not able to reproduce your results. What happens is that your regex is too greedy. And Spans over `</aa><aa>` as well.

Comment: I need to take a closer look at it again, then. The string I'm manipulating comes from a stream. As far I can see it's the only difference between your code and mine. My regex is not greedy enough, though. It doesn't match the part with <dd><ee>e</ee></dd>. What do I miss, here?!

Comment: Multiline comment got me to the solution, in combination with your verification that the regex works. For some reason, there were line breaks and whitespaces but they didn't show. Once I got rid of them, all's working as supposed to. Great!